# Read and write cross domain cookies with single Farm solution

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

Scenario- SharePoint Application pages with two different domain.
I have two different domains, now here is need of access the same cookie from both the domain, I heard that the cookies are worked on the same domain.
So how to implement this?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is it possible or not ?